# How to hide path location in drupal 7?

Tags: uri, files

How to hide path file in drupal? Now it looks like this:

```
http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/document.pdf
```

I want to change to look something like this:

```
http://localhost/drupal/media/view.php?id=6445
```

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by implementing custom menu callback

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
 function mymodule_menu() {
   $items['media/view/%file'] = array(
     'page callback' => 'mymodule_download_file',
     'page arguments' => array(2),
     'access arguments' => array('access content'),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );
   return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback for a file to download
 */
 function mymodule_download_file($file) {
   if($file) {
    file_transfer($file->uri, array('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$file->filename));
   }
   else {
    return drupal_access_denied();
   }
 }
```